# Is there a way to access user defined variables in vsfi file?

Tags: matlab, specman, e

Summary: Is there a way to access user defined variables in vsfi file?

After my simulation is done, in a vsif file, I kick off a post simulation script that will launch Matlab to analyze the output of the DUT.

In order to analyze the data in Matlab I need to compare expected values with observed values. Some of these expected values are defined in my test.e. Is there a way to pass a simulation run variable ( in test.e) to my vsif file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you want is possible, as Specman and Vmanager are different tools. Since you're going the post-processing way, you can just dump a text file from your e code that your Matlab script can read.

Answer (score 1):

The .vsif file is descriptive and read at the beginning of the session, so you can't pass information from a task to another task.
I would suggest the same as Tudor.